# How to test Sharepoint with a Virtual Environment

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I would like to test Sharepoint without a server.
Is it possible to create a virtual server on my computer to do so ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about setting up a virtual server environment, and not about anything SharePoint specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definately. If you have the appropriate disk space, memory requirements and number of processor cores available - you can set up your own virtual machine on a PC.

1. First you need to enable [Hyper-V in the Control Panel](http://blogs.technet.com/b/schadinio/archive/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7.aspx).
2. Second, you need to install Windows Server inside Hyper-V.
3. Third, [Set up the development environment for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx) or [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
4. When that is done, run the command prompt (CMD) to find out your virtual machines IP-address using the command `ipconfig`.
5. Access your SharePoint development environment with remote desktop to the IP-address in your previous step.